# What's the difference between .replace and -replace in powershell?

Tags: powershell, methods, replace

I was under impression that .replace and -replace were the exact same thing, however I found that I could not accomplish some RegEx tasks with .replace that I could with -replace. Could someone please point out what I'm missing?

```
Broken Regex replace:
$a=$a.Replace('.:\\LOGROOT\\', "\\$env:computername\logroot\")


Working Regex replace:
$a=$a -Replace('.:\\LOGROOT\\', "\\$env:computername\logroot\")
```

ps: 
The following URL leads me to think there are .replace options I am unfamiliar with, but I cant seem to find any additional information on how to use them, or how to access the help for these options. http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_regex.htm
Regex.Replace(String, String, String, RegexOptions) and also:
Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator, RegexOptions) methods.

Thank you

Comment: I think `-Replace` is an operator while `.Replace` is a method (on `$a`).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While @Keith Hill's answer explains the difference between `Replace` method and the `-replace` operator, to explain why you might not see the same result, it is because you are using the `String.Replace` method which does string replace and `-replace` operator uses regex replace. You can use the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) method for this purpose and you should see the same effect:

```
[regex]::replace($a,'.:\\LOGROOT\\', "\\$env:computername\logroot\")
```

In short, the `-replace` operator is same as `Regex.Replace` (the particular overload linked above), but in general `Replace()` can be instance or static method that can be doing anything completely different from `-replace`

Comment: Nice, but note an important difference between `-regex` and `[regex]::Replace()`: `-regex` is case-_insensitive_ by default (as PowerShell generally is); more specifically, it is therefore the case-_sensitive_ variant, `-creplace` that corresponds to the .NET method.

Answer (score 19):

They are not the same thing. `.Replace` is a .NET method either on System.String or any other type with an instance method named `Replace`.  `-replace` is a PowerShell operator that that uses regular expressions. Run `man about_operators` to see more info on the `-replace` operator.

Comment: Indeed, to be more specific `a -replace b,c` is the .NET method [`Regex.Replace(a, b, c, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx).