# how to delete one or more spaces at the end of a filename using windows powershell regex?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, scripting

i have a directory containing a lot of files with missformated filenames. some of them does have "spaces" right at the end of the filename. others have some keywords meshed within the filename at the end of the filename string. for example "xxx xxx xxx somewordEng .txt"

im trying to get rid of them using this script, but it wont do yet. Spaces at the end of the Filename (Basename) still there and so is the "Eng" keyword that is somehow added to the word before:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("Eng$","").replace(" {2,}"," ").replace("\s$","") + $_.Extension }

.replace("Eng$","")  is supposed to remove the "Eng" keyword if it appears at the END of the filename (basename), seems not working so far.

.replace(" {2,}"," ")   is supposed to replace 2 or more following spaces with just ONE space within the filename, seems not working so far.

.replace("\s$","")    is supposed to remove spaces at the end of the filename, does not work neither.
```

I searched for powershell regex examples, but it seems nothing worked so far for me. :( cant see the problem yet.

Comment: `.replace` is not `-replace` the latter supports regex. the former is simple wildcards.

Comment: I would like to add that you could totally use the `.Trim()` method to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have here is that the string method `.Replace()` does not support regular expressions which is what you are trying to do here. You should be using the replace operator `-replace` instead. The differences between the two options are covered a little more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10184473/3829407)

The following two examples show this differnce

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> "Te.t".Replace(".","s")
Test

PS C:\Users\mcameron> "Te.t" -Replace ".","s"
ssss
```

**In your case**

```
$_.BaseName -replace "Eng$" -replace " {2,}"," " -replace "\s$"
```

We use the correct operator and you can still "chain" them like you see above. That would remove the trailing word "Eng" and any trailing single whitespace. As well as reduce a group of whitespace to a single space. Also if you are replacing with nothing then you can omit the second parameter.

However you can tighten those together a little if you wanted.

```
$_.BaseName -replace "(Eng|\s+)$" -replace "\s{2,}"," "
```

Comment: hmmm.. ok thanks. but how can i combine those two methods into one line ? i tried your suggestion of using "-replace regex" in combination with the ".replace()" method but still fails atm (or just works partly). see  this example here: 

    dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.replace("nastyKeyword1","").replace("nastyKeyword1"," ") -replace "Eng$" -replace " {2,}"," " -replace "\s$" + $_.Extension }

inserted in that position throws me an error. but i would like to have the substitution done at THAT position, so that i dont have to care about the extension . How can i fix that ?

Comment: Or can i do somethin line {{{   $_.BaseName -replace "(Eng|\s+)$" -replace "\s{2,}"," " .replace("nastyKeyword1","").replace("nastyKeyword2","") }}} somehow ??

Comment: @AxelWerner Don't nest the curly braces like that. They denote a script block. You should be able to experiment with your current logic but use `()` instead. Also you could just `-replace "NastyKeyword1|NastyKeyword2|andsoon"`