# Powershell - replace string in file

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I'm trying to edit the contents of a config file called prefs.cfg. It has two lines:

```
Server.Name "test"
VoIP.Enabled "1"
```

I'm trying to get more comfortable with replacing string but I seem to keep messing up.

I wrote something out, I would appreciate if someone could point in my script where I'm going wrong .

```
$prefs = Get-Content .\prefs.cfg

$prefs | Select-String "Server.Name"

$servername = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Server Name"

Write-Host $servername

$prefs -replace $servername

$prefs
```

Answer (score 1):

- Although you are passing `$prefs` to [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) and `-replace`, the results of those operations are not being assigned to variables. So you cannot use them later.
- One argument is being passed to `-replace`. It expects two: what to replace, and what to replace it with. **Edit:** if a single argument is provided, this is taken as "what to replace". As "what to replace it with" is not provided, it will be replaced with nothing (i.e. deleted)
- `Select-String` and `-replace` use regex. Seems a bit overkill for this task. [`Where-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and `.Replace` are perfectly up to the task.

---

```
$prefs = Get-Content .\prefs.cfg

# Get the line using Where. * is wildcard
$oldServerLine = $prefs | Where-object {$_ -like "Server.Name*"}

$servername = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Server Name"

Write-Host $servername

# Replace old line with new line. ` is the escape character so you get " as expected.
$newPrefs = $prefs.Replace($oldServerLine,"Server.Name `"$servername`"")

$newPrefs
```

<sub>[Related: difference between -replace and .Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184156/whats-the-difference-between-replace-and-replace-in-powershell)</sub>

Comment: Ah I actually see where Im making my mistake now in the script, I will also be looking into this Where-Object some more, thank you

Comment: Just for clarity if `-replace` has no second argument, it replaces with what is has: nothing. So this is valid to delete a pattern.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks, added to answer.