# Open and save an xml config file with powershell

Tags: xml, file, powershell, save

I am trying to create a script to modify the content of a config file, save it and launch the associated program. The file is apparently an xml file and with the script I created I save it in a normal text file. That might be the reason why my program won't start anymore. So how can I save in xml ?

Here is the script:

```
$content = [XML](Get-Content("path\file.config"))
$content = $content.replace("IP address","Other IP address")
$content | out-file "path\file.config"
```

Thanks in advance

Ben

Comment: First off: **Please don't use regex on xml**. There's not anything obviously wrong with your script as it is. Could you show the contents of `file.config`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I agree with the sentiment; bear in mind [`.Replace` is string replace whereas `-replace` is regex replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184156/whats-the-difference-between-replace-and-replace-in-powershell)

Comment: Hi guys, I used @slong16 solution and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $content = Get-Content "path\file.config" | Out-String
 $content = $content.replace("IP address","Other IP address")
 $content = ([xml]$content).save("path\file.config")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make sense as it's partly dealing with `xml` and part with text. I've tried to illustrate this with comments to the below, and how you can resolve this.

**Example input**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mytag>IP address</mytag>
```

**Breakdown**

```
# this line imports the file, and turns it into an XML object. so far so good.
$content = [XML](Get-Content("path\file.config"))

# this line leads to an error:
# Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlDocument] does not contain a method named 'replace'
$content = $content.replace("IP address","Other IP address")

# this line will try to export the xml object (unsuccessfully)
$content | out-file "path\file.config"
```

**Approach 1 - treat as text**

```
$content = (Get-Content("path\file.config"))
$content = $content.replace("IP address","Other IP address")
$content | out-file "path\file.config"
```

**Approach 2 - treat as xml**

```
$content = [XML](Get-Content("path\file.config"))
$content = $content.mytag = "Other IP Address"
$content.OuterXml | out-file "path\file.config"
```

Comment: Hi there, thank for your help but I didn't manage to make it work... I am a noob with PS so it's porbably my fault. Thanks anyways =)