# powershell string replace regular expression does not work

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm using the Replace function for a string with a regular expression:

```
PS C:\>  "Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au".Replace('Domain: *','')
Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au
```

However this works:

```
PS C:\>  "Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au" -Replace 'Domain: *',''
ad.unsw.edu.au
```

Can someone please explain why the string replace method does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough when I show you how it will work?  ;-)

```
"Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au" -Replace 'Domain:\s*',''
```

Comment: Thanks.  However it still is not the full picture:

Comment: `PS C:\> "Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au".Replace('Domain:\s*','')`
still does not do text replacement.

Comment: Actually I meant to use the "normal" Powershell syntax instead of the method. Then it will work.

Comment: "...".Replace() is a string replace method not a regex replace method. That's why it behaves differently. It's been asked already here -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184156/whats-the-difference-between-replace-and-replace-in-powershell)

Comment: `[regex]::replace('Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au','Domain:\s+','')`
So this would work as you probably expect it.

Comment: Thanks to all!  Works as  documented.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessary to use regex for replace, you can do it:

```
"Domain:                    ad.unsw.edu.au".Replace('Domain:', '').Trim()
```