# Cannot replace path

Tags: powershell

I want to replace string in `$test` that contains `$folder`, there's no syntax error but nothing is replaced:

```
$folder = 'c:\test'
$test = 'c:\test\subtest\' -replace $folder, ""
```

> $test still contains 'c:\test\subtest\'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$folder = 'c:\test'
$test = 'c:\test\subtest\'.replace($folder,'')
```

If you just want a straight string replace you can use the `Replace()` Method, rather than using your current `-Replace` Operator which uses regex replace.

Related: [What's the difference between .replace and -replace in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184156/whats-the-difference-between-replace-and-replace-in-powershell)

Comment: Subsequent question: when I applied it to list directories, I don't understand why it doesn't work :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262365/powershell-column-directory-empty

Answer (score 2):

`-replace` takes a regex as its input, and in a regex, `\t` means "tab character".

```
$folder = 'c:\\test'
$test = 'c:\test\subtest\' -replace $folder, ""
```

will give the desired result.

Comment: it works but for the reason are you sure: it's the same with $folder = 'c:\anothertest' I must use $folder = 'c:\\anothertest'

Comment: Yes, and `\a` is a regex metacharacter for "start of string".

Comment: Ah ok thanks :) then It's easier to use .replace because my usecase is generic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262365/powershell-column-directory-empty

Comment: A more generic approach would be `-replace [regex]::Escape($folder), ''`.

Comment: Wouldn’t that kind of defeat the purpose of using a regex in the first place?

Comment: @TimPietzcker True. But since the OP apparently didn't mean to provide a regular expression in the first place ...