# Column Directory empty?

Tags: powershell

I thought that applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261797/powershell-cannot-replace-path) about replacing a path would work for:

```
$folder = 'C:\test'

$List = Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime
$List | Format-Table name, LastWriteTime, @{Label="Directory"; Expression={$_.Directory.Replace($folder, "")}}
```

Instead I get nothing in Directory column whereas I should get

> \subfolder\

since the files are in

> c:\test\subfolder

```
Name       LastWriteTime         Directory
----       -------------         ---------
test.1.png 7/21/2018 10:20:44 PM
test.2.png 7/21/2018 10:21:16 PM
test.3.png 7/21/2018 10:21:43 PM
subfolder  9/10/2018 6:53:28 PM
```

Comment: Use `$_.DirectoryName`

Comment: @LotPings thanks it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Directory` member of `Get-ChildItem` is a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`. It has a member, `Name`, that can be used.

```
PS H:\clan\2018-09-05> (Get-ChildItem).Directory | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

Try using:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $_.Directory.Name }
```