# What is the difference between [Regex]::Replace() and -replace?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I understood the difference between `.Replace()` and `-replace`, but what are `-replace` and `[Regex]::Replace()`?

I tested the 2 following codes, but for me the results are the exactly the same.

I also referred to PowerShell Cookbook(O'reilly), and it says

> ([Regex] is) extremely advanced regular expression replacement

I want to know what `[Regex]` can but `-replace` can't.

```
$line = "Loosen the socket by turning it#counterclockwise."
$line = $line -Replace "([a-z])#([a-z])","`$1 `$2"
$line

# Loosen the socket by turning it counterclockwise.

$line.GetType()
# IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
# -------- -------- ----                                     --------
# True     True     String                                   System.Object

$line2 = "Loosen the socket by turning it#counterclockwise."
$line2 = [Regex]::Replace($line3,"([a-z])#([a-z])","`$1 `$2")
$line2

# Loosen the socket by turning it counterclockwise.

$line2.GetType()
# IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
# -------- -------- ----                                     --------
# True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: Try against `$line = "A#b"`, you will see it immediately (`-replace` is case-insensitive by default). Besides, you cannot manipulate a match with a callback when using `-replace`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as of today (version 6.1) [you can](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.1.0) ;)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Wow. So, only case-sensitivity is left, right?

Comment: From my perspective it boils down to: use `-replace` until you run into something that doesn't work. Switch to `[regex]::Replace()` when you do. Operator syntax is simpler to write and understand, so stick to that as long as you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between .replace and -replace in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184156/whats-the-difference-between-replace-and-replace-in-powershell)

Comment: @JamesC: Related, but not a duplicate, because the linked question is about the `[string]` type's `.Replace` (instance) method, not about the `[regex]` type's (static) method of the same name.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can have case sensitivity: `-creplace`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I know that, the question is not about `-creplace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Fish's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333140/45375) contains good pointers, but let me frame things a little differently, in part inspired by [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)' comments:

- ***PowerShell's* [`-replace` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator) is a *friendly wrapper*** for the *.NET* [`[Regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace) *method*.

  - Given that PowerShell is built on the .NET framework, it is a common pattern for PowerShell to surface .NET functionality in a simpler, higher-level fashion.
- An important difference in default behavior is that **`-replace` is *case-INsensitive* by default**, in line with PowerShell's behavior in general.

  - Use variant `-creplace` for case-*sensitive* replacements.
- **`-replace` only provides a *subset* of the functionality** provided by the various `[Regex]::Replace()` overloads.

  - The functionality gap has narrowed in PowerShell *Core* v6.1.0+, which now also offers *callback* functionality via a script block passed to `-replace`, thanks to work by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen); e.g.,
    `'1 + 1 = 2' -replace '\d+', { [int] $_.Value * 2 }` yields `'2 + 2 = 4'` and is the equivalent of:
    `[regex]::replace('1 + 1 = 2', '\d+', { param($match) [int] $match.Value * 2 })`
- **If `-replace` is good enough for a given use case, use *it*** rather than `[regex]::Replace()`.

  - The syntax of method calls differs from the rest of PowerShell, and there are subtleties around type conversion and long-term stability of code; it is therefore generally preferable to stick with native PowerShell features (cmdlets and operators), if feasible.
  - However, if `-replace` doesn't provide the functionality you need, calling `[regex]::Replace()` directly is a great advanced option; note that `Replace()` also exists as an *instance* method, in which case it offers additional functionality - e.g., the ability to [limit the number of replacements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_System_Int32_); e.g.:

    ```
    # Replace only the first two 'o' instances.
    PS> $re = [regex] 'o'; $re.Replace('fooo', '@', 2)
    f@@o
    ```

Answer (score 3):

`-Replace` is a powershell operator that replaces X with Y and cannot be configured to do anything else.

`[Regex]` is a .NET class which contains a method called `Replace` and has many overloads that can configure and control how the string is replaced.

`-replace` probably uses `[Regex]::Replace` under the hood.

The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the `Regex.Replace` method contains all the many different ways it can be called.

The [methods and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2) contained in the Regex class.