# Issue with Powershell update string in each file within a folder

Tags: powershell

I have a set of SQL files stored in a folder. These files contain the schema name in the format `dbo_xxxxxx` where xxxxxx is the year & month e.g. `dbo_202001`, `dbo_202002` etc. I want the powershell script to replace the xxxxx number with a new one in each of these SQL files. I'm using the below script to achieve that. However, the issue is that it seems to partially match on the old string (instead of matching on the full string) and puts the new string in place e.g. instead of replacing `[dbo_202001]` with `[dbo_201902]`, anywhere it finds `d`, `b`, `o` etc. it replaces it with `[dbo_201902]`. Anyway to fix this?

```
$sourceDir = "C:\SQL_Scripts"
$SQLScripts = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir *.sql -rec
foreach ($file in $SQLScripts)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "[dbo_202001]", "[dbo_201902]" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath -NoNewline
}
```

Comment: `-replace` is for regex, escape the brackets so that it's not a range of characters.

Comment: `$_ -replace "\[dbo_202001\]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) and [marsze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060966/marsze) have provided the crucial pointers: **since the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operates on *regexes* ([regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)), you must `\`-escape special characters such as `[` and `]` in order to treat them *verbatim* (as literals)**:
`$_ -replace '\[dbo_202001\]', '[dbo_201902]'`

While use of the `-replace` operator is generally preferable, the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method directly offers *verbatim* (literal) string replacements and is therefore also faster than `-replace`.
Typically, this won't matter, but in situations similar to yours, where many iterations are involved, it may (note that the replacement is case-*sensitive*):
`$_.Replace('[dbo_202001]', '[dbo_201902]')`

See the **bottom section** for **guidance on when to use `-replace` vs. `.Replace()`**.

---

**The performance of your code can be greatly improved:**

```sh
$sourceDir = 'C:\SQL_Scripts'
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File $sourceDir -Filter *.sql -Recurse)
{
  # CAVEAT: This overwrites the files in-place.
  Set-Content -NoNewLine $file.PSPath -Value `
    (Get-Content -Raw $file.PSPath).Replace('[dbo_202001]', '[dbo_201902]')
}
```

- Since you're reading the whole file into memory anyway, using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch to read it as a *single, multi-line string* (rather than an *array of lines*) on which you can perform a *single* `.Replace()` operation is much faster.
- [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s `-NoNewLine` switch is needed to prevent an additional newline from getting appended on writing back to the file.
- Note the use of the `-Value` parameter rather than the *pipeline* to provide the file content. Since there's only a single string object to write here, it makes little difference, but in general, with many objects to write that are *already collected in memory*, `Set-Content ... -Value $array` is much faster than `$array | Set-Content ...`.

---

#### Guidance on use of the `-replace` *operator* vs. the `.Replace()` *method*:

- [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is the PowerShell-specific [regex (regular-expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based string replacement *operator*,
- whereas [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) is a *method* of the *.NET `[string]` type*. ([`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)), which performs verbatim (literal) string replacements.

Note that **both features invariably replace *all* matches they find**, and, conversely, **return the original string if none are found**.

Generally, **PowerShell's `-replace` operator is a more natural fit in PowerShell code -  both syntactically and due to its case-insensitivity - and offers more functionality**, thanks to being regex-based.

The `.Replace()` method is limited to *verbatim* replacements and in Windows PowerShell to case-*sensitive* ones, but has the advantage of being faster and not having to worry about escaping special characters in its arguments:

- **Only use the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method**:

  - for **invariably *verbatim*** string replacements
  - with the following case-sensitivity:

    - *PowerShell [Core] v6+*: **case-*sensitive* by default**, optionally case-*insensitive* via an additional argument; e.g.:

      ```sh
      'FOO'.Replace('o', '@', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')
      ```
    - *Windows PowerShell*: **invariably(!) case-*sensitive***
  - if functionally feasible, when performance matters
- **Otherwise, use PowerShell's `-replace` operator** (covered in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)):

  - for ***regex*-based replacements:**

    - enables **sophisticated, pattern-based matching and dynamic construction of replacement strings**
    - To **escape metacharacters** (characters with special syntactic meaning) in order to treat them verbatim:

      - in the pattern (regex) argument: `\`-escape them (e.g., `\.` or `\[`)
      - in the replacement argument: only `$` is special, escape it as `$$`.
    - To **escape an entire operand in order to treat its value verbatim** (to effectively perform literal replacement):

      - in the pattern argument: call `[regex]::Escape($pattern)`
      - in the replacement argument: call `$replacement.Replace('$', '$$')`
  - with the following case-sensitivity:

    - **case-*insensitive* by default**
    - optionally **case-*sensitive*** via its `c`-prefixed variant, **`-creplace`**
  - Note: `-replace` is a PowerShell-friendly wrapper around the [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) method that doesn't expose *all* of the latter's functionality, notably not its ability to limit the *number of replacements*; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335337/45375) for how to use it.

Note that **`-replace` can directly operation on *arrays*** (collections) of strings as the LHS, in which case the **replacement is performed on each element, which is *stringified on demand*.**

Thanks to PowerShell's fundamental [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature, `.Replace()` too can operate on arrays, but only if all elements are already *strings*. Also, unlike `-replace`, which always also *returns* an array if the LHS is one, member-access enumeration returns a single string if the input object happens to be a *single-element* array.

As an aside: similar considerations apply to the use of PowerShell's `-split` operator vs. the `[string]` type's `.Split()` method - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).

**Examples**:

`-replace` -  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for syntax details:

```sh
# Case-insensitive replacement.
# Pattern operand (regex) happens to be a verbatim string.
PS> 'foo' -replace 'O', '@'
f@@

# Case-sensitive replacement, with -creplace
PS> 'fOo' -creplace 'O', '@'
f@o

# Regex-based replacement with verbatim replacement: 
# metacharacter '$' constrains the matching to the *end*
PS> 'foo' -replace 'o$', '@'
fo@

# Regex-based replacement with dynamic replacement: 
# '$&' refers to what the regex matched
PS> 'foo' -replace 'o$', '>>$&<<'
fo>>o<<

# PowerShell [Core] only:
# Dynamic replacement based on a script block.
PS> 'A1' -replace '\d', { [int] $_.Value + 1 }
A2

# Array operation, with elements stringified on demand:
PS> 1..3 -replace '^', '0'
01
02
03

# Escape a regex metachar. to be treated verbatim.
PS> 'You owe me $20' -replace '\$20', '20 dollars'
You owe me 20 dollars. 

# Ditto, via a variable and [regex]::Escape()
PS> $var = '$20'; 'You owe me $20' -replace [regex]::Escape($var), '20 dollars'
You owe me 20 dollars.

# Escape a '$' in the replacement operand so that it is always treated verbatim:
PS> 'You owe me 20 dollars' -replace '20 dollars', '$$20'
You owe me $20

# Ditto, via a variable and [regex]::Escape()
PS> $var = '$20'; 'You owe me 20 dollars' -replace '20 dollars', $var.Replace('$', '$$')
You owe me $20.
```

`.Replace()`:

```sh
# Verbatim, case-sensitive replacement.
PS> 'foo'.Replace('o', '@')
f@@

# No effect, because matching is case-sensitive.
PS> 'foo'.Replace('O', '@')
foo

# PowerShell [Core] v6+ only: opt-in to case-INsensitivity:
PS> 'FOO'.Replace('o', '@', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')
F@@

# Operation on an array, thanks to member-access enumeration:
# Returns a 2 -element array in this case.
PS> ('foo', 'goo').Replace('o', '@')
f@@
g@@

# !! Fails, because not all array elements are *strings*:
PS> ('foo', 42).Replace('o', '@')
... Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'Replace'. ...
```