# Replacing text that includes backslashes in a txt file with Powershell v1

Tags: powershell, replace

If I replace just the text there is no problem but the problem occurs when I replace the text that includes backslashes that is when the error occurs. How can I approach this to accept the new parameter? Here is what I have:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\TEST.txt' -Raw) -replace 'Log', 'Log\400\Department3' |
  Set-Content -Path 'C:\TEST.txt'
```

Comment: In short: PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) _operator_ is _regex_-based and case-_insensitive_ by default. To perform _literal_ replacement, `\ `-escape metacharacters in the pattern or call `[regex]::Escape()`.
By contrast, the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) _method_ performs _literal_ replacement and is case-_sensitive_, _invariably_ in Windows PowerShell, _by default_ in PowerShell (Core).
See the [answer to the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375).

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @Sam.