# Powershell Regex - Replace between string A and string B only if contains string C

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file which looks like this

```
ABC01|01
Random data here 2131233154542542542
More random data
STRING-C
A bit more random stuff
&(%+
ABC02|01
Random data here 88888888
More random data 22222
STRING-D
A bit more random stuff
&(%+
```

I'm trying to make a script to Find everything between `ABC01` and `&(%+` **ONLY** if it contains `STRING-C`

I came up with this for regex `ABC([\s\S]*?)STRING-C(?s)(.*?)&\(%\+`

I'm getting this content from a text file with `get-content`.

`$bad_content = gc $bad_file -raw`

I want to do something like `($bad_content.replace($pattern,"")` to remove the regex match.

How can I replace my matches in the file with nothing? I'm not even sure if my regex is correct but on regex101 it seems to find the strings I'm needing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex works with the sample input given, but not *robustly*, because if the order of blocks were reversed, it would mistakenly match *across* the blocks and remove *both*.

[Tim Biegeleisen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68473196/45375) shows a regex that fixes the problem, via a negative lookahead assertion (`(?!...)`).

Let me show how to make it work from PowerShell:

- You need to use the regex-based [`-replace` *operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), not the literal-substring-based [`.Replace()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace):<sup>[1]</sup> to apply it.
- To read the input string from a file, use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch to ensure that the file is read as a *single, multi-line string*; by default, `Get-Content` returns an *array (stream) of lines*, which would cause the `-replace` operation to be applied to *each line individually*.

```
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -replace '(?s)ABC01(?:(?!&\(%\+).)*?STRING-C.*?&\(%\+'
```

Not specifying *replacement text* (as the optional 2nd RHS operand to `-replace`) replaces the match with the *empty string* and therefore effectively *removes* what was matched.

The regex borrowed from Tim's answer is simplified a bit, by using the inline method of specifying matching options to tun on the *single-line* option (`(?s)`) at the start of the expression, which makes subsequent `.` instances match *newlines too* (a shorter and more efficient alternative to `[\s\S]`).

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375) for the juxtaposition of the two, including guidance on when to use which.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it, @shadow2020. Kudos to [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) for coming up with the robust regex.

Answer (score 3):

We can use a tempered dot trick when matching between the two markers to ensure that we don't cross the ending marker before matching `STRING-C`:

```regex
ABC01(?:(?!&\(%\+)[\s\S])*?STRING-C[\s\S]*?&\(%\+
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
ABC01                   match the starting marker
(?:(?!&\(%\+)[\s\S])*?  without crossing the ending marker
STRING-C                match the nearest STRING-C marker
[\s\S]*?                then match all content, across lines, until reaching
&\(%\+                  the ending marker
```

Comment: Love the solution but I'm getting the same result as my own pattern. If I do this, `[regex]::match($pattern, $exampledata)` I get a value of STRING-C and nothing else. I need the entire text to be replaced and not just the string-c

Comment: If you check the regex demo link, you'll see that in fact my pattern matches the entire block from start to end marker.  There must be some other with Powershell (with which sadly I have zero experience using).

Comment: @shadow2020 Tim's regex works perfectly fine, you should be doing `[regex]::Matches($exampledata, $pattern)` not vice-versa.