# Get the current working directory or any directory with "/" instead of "\" in powershell script

Tags: powershell, pwd

In order to deliver the current working directory adress to a program. I need to provide the directory Path separated by forward slashes `/`. The program does not accept a string containing backslashes.

Currently, the `pwd`-Command delivers the following:
`C:\testdir1\testdir2`

I want the following string:
`C:/testdir1/testdir2`

Is there an easy way to transform this directory adress in a powershell script?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)<sup>[1]</sup> to perform (invariably global) string replacements (since it is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, a verbatim `\` must be escaped as `\\`); the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) contains the PowerShell session's current *location* (which, if the underlying [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers) is the `FileSystem` provider, is a *directory*):

```
$PWD -replace '\\', '/'
```

If you want to ensure that the resulting path is a file-system-native path (one not based on PowerShell-only drives):

```
$PWD.ProviderPath -replace '\\', '/'
```

If there's a chance that the current location is from a provider *other* than the file-system (e.g., a registry-based drive such as `HKLM:`).

```
(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath -replace '\\', '/'
```

---

<sup>[1] In this simple case, calling the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) is an alternative, but the `-replace` operator is more PowerShell-idiomatic and offers superior functionality. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375) contrasts the two.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Fast code but seems to works as expected

```
# Original path
$Path = "C:\testdir1\testdir2"
Write-Host "Original Path is:" $Path
#Replace \ by /
$Changed = $Path -replace '\\', '/'
Write-Host "changed path:" $Changed
```

**Output**

```
Original Path is: C:\testdir1\testdir2
changed path: C:/testdir1/testdir2
```