# how to replace text ($) with quotation marks in a text file by using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to replace the text ($) with quotation marks in a text file by using PowerShell

Here is the code I am trying, But not giving expected results:

```
$FilePath = "C:\PT\Test\"
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter *.TXT | ForEach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.FullName) | Foreach-Object {
 $_ -replace  ',"$"', ',"$",'
} | Set-Content $_.FullName
 }
```

Comment: Should just need to escape it, try: `"\$",""`, or use the dot net method which will read all characters literally: `$_.Replace("$","")`

Answer (score 2):

The [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

- **uses a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) as the search-pattern** operand, and therefore requires a *verbatim* `$` to be  *escaped as* **`\$`** in order to be interpreted as such (an unescaped `$` is a regex *metacharacter* representing the *end of the input string*)
- also uses `$` as a metacharacter in the ***substitution* operand**, namely to refer to the text that the regex captured (`$&`) or parts thereof (e.g. `$1` to refer to what the first *capture group* (`(...)`) captured). In this case, escape it as **`$$`**.

  - Note: Situationally, even an *unescaped* `$` may work, namely if, in combination with the subsequent characters, if any,  it cannot be interpreted as a placeholder such as `$&` or `$1`. However, in the interest of robustness it is better to escape.

Therefore, use:

```sh
PS> ',"$"20' -replace ',"\$"', ',"$$",'
,"$",20
```

---

Taking a step back:

As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) suggests, **for *verbatim* string replacements**, the **`.Replace()` string *method*** is sufficient, whose use doesn't necessitate escaping, and which is faster to boot:

```sh
PS> ',"$"20'.Replace(',"$"', ',"$",')
,"$",20
```

**Caveat**: Unlike `-replace`, **`.Replace()` is case-*sensitive*** - *invariably* in *Windows PowerShell* and *by default* in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375) for a detailed juxtaposition of `-replace` and `.Replace()`, including how to perform escaping for `-replace` *programmatically*.

---

To **put it all together**, along **with an optimization** that reads each file *in full*, with `Get-Content -Raw`, for much faster processing (to avoid appending a trailing newline, `-NoNewLine` is used with `Set-Content`):

```sh
$FilePath = "C:\PT\Test"
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter *.TXT | ForEach-Object {
  (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName).Replace(',"$"', ',"$",') | 
    Set-Content -NoNewLine $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70443648/how-to-replace-text-with-quotation-marks-in-a-text-file-by-using-powershell#comment124523572_70443648) in his comment, the `$` is a reserved character in *regex* known as [Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#anchors), if you want to match a literal `$` using `-replace` you would need to [escape it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#escaping-characters): `\$`:

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter *.TXT | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace ',"\$"',',"$",' |
    Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

The other alternative is to use the [`.Replace(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) string method which will match literal characters.

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter *.TXT | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw).Replace(',"$"',',"$",') |
    Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

By looking at your code seems like you want to replace `,"$"` with `,"$",`, if this was not the case let me know.