# Remove "." in file name while retaining file extension

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PS to rename a bunch files within a big share and one of the requirements is to remove a dot from the file name. I have tested a few things with my rather basic skills and of course the most basic of scripts zap the file extension.
I finally came up with something like this:

```
gci *.xlsx | rename-item -newname {$_.Name.replace(".","") + $_.extension }
```

But that adds the extension to the end of the filename (while keeping the file extension intact)

I thought I could zap the last four symbols using something like this:

```
gci *.xlsx | rename-item -newname { $_.basename.substring(0,$_.basename.length-4) + $_.extension }
```

Overall this seems like an overly complicated operation which could also mess up files without dots (unless I specify xlsx as only 4 symbols to be removed)

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to an easier solution? ;-)

Comment: Is it the first dot? The last dot? All dots? Please provide an example file name or two :)

Comment: take a look at the `.BaseName` property instead of the `.Name` prop. [*grin*] ///// also, PLEASE add 2 or 3 sample file names & the desired result for each to your Question.

Comment: It is actually the first dot only that I want to remove so "this_file.looks_like-this.xlsx" There are hundreds of files in various subfolders that I want to catch all at once.

Comment: So you want `$_.BaseName.Remove($_.BaseName.IndexOf('.'), 1) + $_.Extension` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with your second attempt: using the `.BaseName` and `.Extension` properties of the [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances<sup>[1]</sup> output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) allows you to modify the base name (the file name *without its extension*) separately, and then re-append the extension to form the full file name:

```
Get-ChildItem *.xlsx | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '\.') + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

The above uses the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) *operator* to remove all `.` instances from the base name; because `.` is a regex *metacharacter* (representing any single character), it must be *escaped* as `\.` in order to be used literally.
In this simple case, you could have used the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` *method* as well (`$_.BaseName.Replace('.', '')`), but `-replace` offers more features and has fewer surprises - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375) for more information.

Case in point: Say you wanted to remove only the *first* `.` from the base name; `-replace` allows you to do that as follows (but you couldn't do it with `.Replace()`):

```
'foo.bar.baz' -replace '\.(.*)$', '$1' # -> 'foobar.baz'
```

---

<sup>[1] `.BaseName` isn't a native property of this type; instead, it is a property that *PowerShell* decorates instances of the type with, using its [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763).</sup>

Comment: Cheers, you are a gentleman and a wizard!  Added -recurse to catch all subfolders for the end result being:(in case anyone needs it in the future)  "Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.xlsx | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '\.') + $_.Extension }"