# newline not working powershell, while replacing

Tags: powershell, replace, newline

I'm just trying to add a linebreak before UNION, I've tried both of the following commands.
The all modify the file (Date gets updated) But it doesn't add the new line.

```
(Get-Content \\C\ELL.sql) -replace "UNION select hash(0)","`r`nUNION select hash(0)" | Set-Content \\C\ELL.sql

(Get-Content \\C\ELL.sql) -replace 'UNION select hash(0)','`r`nUNION select hash(0)' | Set-Content \\C\ELL.sql
```

My replaces worked in the past, when no line break was involved.

Anyone knows what's causing the issue?
Thank you

Comment: give this a try: `.Replace("UNION select hash(0)", "$([Environment]::NewLine)UNION select hash(0)")` since you're using literal string replacement and not regex

Comment: I'm just confused at how the entire command should look like, since i've always been using -replace, instead of .replace
For me it's giving me errors, but i think i got the syntax wrong

Comment: `(Get-Content \\C\ELL.sql -Raw).Replace("UNION select hash(0)", "$([Environment]::NewLine)UNION select hash(0)")`

Comment: ( and ) are special regex characters that would need to be backslashed

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't with *newlines*, it is due to the fact that the **[`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator** is **[*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based**.

Therefore, your search pattern, `"UNION select hash(0)"` effectively only matches `UNION select hash0` (note the absence of `(` and `)`), which therefore doesn't match the intended lines, so no replacement occurs at all.

The reason is that `(...)` in a regex is a *capture group* - **`(` and `)` are *not* treated *literally*** - you have to ***escape* them**, namely as `\(` and `\)`:

```
(Get-Content \\C\ELL.sql) -replace "UNION select hash\(0\)", "`r`n`$&" |
  Set-Content \\C\ELL.sql
```

Note the use of `$&` (escaped as `` `$& `` to prevent *PowerShell* from interpreting it) in the substitution operand, which refers to what the regex captured (matched), obviating the need to repeat the text. You're free to use literal text in the replacement, but note that any *literal* `$` characters must be escaped as `$$` (or, inside a `"..."` string, as `` `$`$ ``); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for a summary of what `$`-prefixed placeholders are supported.

You can alternatively perform the escaping *programmatically*, on your entire string, using [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape):

```
(Get-Content \\C\ELL.sql) -replace ([regex]::Escape("UNION select hash(0)"), "`r`n`$&" |
  Set-Content \\C\ELL.sql
```

---

That said, as [Santigo Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you could use the `[string]` type's **[`.Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) .NET *method***, which (only) **performs *literal* replacements**, but there are two caveats:

- Unlike `-replace`, `.Replace()` is case-*sensitive*, *invariably* in *Windows PowerShell* and *by default* in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.
- You don't get the convenience of referring to (parts of) what was matched in the replacement string (such as `$&` used with `-replace`), which is also a literal.

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375) for **general guidance on when to use `-replace` vs. `.Replace()`**

Comment: Your first command worked!
Just curious is there a way to do it without using the previous text matched ( $& ) 
Just in case We want to put the new line anywhere in the middle

Comment: @KeyleT,  you're free to use literal text in the replacement, but note that any _literal_ `$` characters must be escaped as `$$` (or, inside a `"..."` string, as `\`$\`$`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for a summary of what `$`-prefixed placeholders are supported (I've also just updated the answer with this information).