# Powershell Get-item -replace issue with special characters and single quotes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace some text in a bunch of ps1 script files. Normally this is no issue, but i'm having some difficulty when the replace string is containing both special characters like "$" along with single quotes.
I have tried to escape the special characters but just cannot get it working.
The specific text i want to replace is..

```
'WORKVPN1*')
```

with

```
'WORKVPN1*') -and ($_.VPN -notlike 'WORKVPN2*')
```

I have tried the following code which doesnt work.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\*.ps1" | ForEach-Object -Process {(Get-Content $_) -Replace "'WORKVPN1*')" , "WORKVPN1*'`) -and `(`$_.VPN -notlike 'WORKVPN2*'`)" | Set-Content $_}
```

Comment: -replace uses regex, so any regex characters would have to be backslashed.  This is a common question.

Comment: backslashed how exactly? i have tried both ` and  \ and neither is working

Answer (score 1):

- **For *verbatim* (literal) replacements, `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), requires *escaping* of *both* the regex operand *and* the substitution operand, albeit *using different mechanisms***.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for background information.
- Unless you need *up-front string expansion* (interpolation), before the *results* are passed to the underlying .NET APIs, **avoid use of [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)** with `-replace` (and `-match` and `switch -Regex`).

  - Even then it's **best to use [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)** and - if needed - use them as part of *expressions* to splice in the dynamic parts
    (e.g. `'a ' + $var + ' b'` instead of `"a $var b"`)

    - Using `'...'` quoting avoids potential confusion that may arise with `"..."` strings over which parts of the string are expanded (interpolated) by PowerShell up front vs. what the .NET regex engine ends up seeing.
    - Notably, in the substitution operand `$_` has special meaning to the regex engine, but using it inside `"..."` would expand the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) instead; compare `'can' -replace '^', '$_'` - which doubles the input string, as intended (`cancan`) - with `'can' -replace '^', "$_"`, which yields just `can`, because the automatic `$_` variable expanded to the *empty string* in the absence of a pipeline context.

Applied to your case:

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter *.ps1 | 
  ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace '''WORKVPN1\*''\)', 
                                     '$& -and ($$_.VPN -notlike ''WORKVPN2*'')"' | 
      Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName
  }
```

Note:

- `''` is needed to escape `'` chars. embedded inside `'...'` strings
- Regex metacharacters `*` and `)` are individually `\`-escaped.

  - Alternatively, for *programmatic* escaping, use [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)
- `$&` in the substitution operand refers to what the regex captured (that is, *verbatim* `'WORKVPN1*')`
- `$$` is used to escape the `$` character in the substitution operand meant to be used *verbatim* - `$` characters are the *only* characters that require escaping in a substitution operand - see [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)

---

An **alternative** is to **use *verbatim* (literal) replacements** using the `[string]` type's **[`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) *method***, which *directly and exclusively* performs verbatim replacements:

- However, this necessitates *repeating* verbatim parts in the replacement string.
- Also, this method is case-*sensitive*, *invariably* in Windows PowerShell, and *by default* in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

  - By contrast, PowerShell's `-replace` operator is case-*insensitive* by default, and offers case-sensitivity via its `-creplace` variant.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375) for guidance on when to use `-replace` vs. `.Replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

-replace using regex, so escape the regex characters.  This method does it for you.

```
[regex]::escape("'WORKVPN1*')")

'WORKVPN1\*'\)
```

.replace() doesn't use regex, but this overload is case sensitive:

```
$string.replace("'WORKVPN1*')", "whatever")
```

I'm just backslashing the star and the parens.  You don't have to backquote the parens in the replacement text.  $$ is the code for a literal $ in -replace.

```
"'WORKVPN1*')" -Replace "'WORKVPN1\*'\)", 
  "WORKVPN1*') -and (`$`$_.VPN -notlike 'WORKVPN2*')"

WORKVPN1*') -and ($_.VPN -notlike 'WORKVPN2*')
```

By the way, I'm not sure where these -replace codes are buried in the docs:

```
$number Substitutes the last submatch matched by group number.
${name} Substitutes the last submatch matched by a named capture of the form
(?<name>).
$$ Substitutes a single "$" literal.
$& Substitutes a copy of the entire match itself.
$` Substitutes all the text from the argument string before the matching portion.
$' Substitutes all the text of the argument string after the matching portion.
$+ Substitutes the last submatch captured.
$_ Substitutes the entire argument string.
```

In .replace(), you would still have to backquote the dollar sign, because of the double-quotes.

```
"'WORKVPN1*')".Replace("'WORKVPN1*')",
  "WORKVPN1*') -and (`$_.VPN -notlike 'WORKVPN2*')")

WORKVPN1*') -and ($_.VPN -notlike 'WORKVPN2*')
```

Comment: i understand what your saying, but this isnt working for my get-childitem specific use case where i need to replace the text in multiple files like my example code.