# Shorten a variable long file name by strings in the front and end

Tags: powershell, substring

I want to shorten this file name from '**210 8th Waverly Updated Submittal (#26 0100-15.0 260100-015.00 - Short Circuit & Protective Device Coordination Study (For Rushing Review)).txt**'

to '**26 0100-15.0 260100-015.00 - Short Circuit & Protective Device Coordination Study.txt**'

I use the pound (#) sign to clip the front, and the text '(For Rushing Review)' to clip the end.

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\*Rushing*.txt' | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.substring($_.BaseName.lastindexof('(#') + 15, $_.BaseName.IndexOf('(For Rushing Review)')-$_.BaseName.lastindexof('(#') + 15)+$_.Extension }
```

But I get the error Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"

Because of the variable length of the file name, I need to use a variable for the end of the substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335337/45375) to extract the substring of interest:

```
$baseName = '210 8th Waverly Updated Submittal (#26 0100-15.0 260100-015.00 - Short Circuit & Protective Device Coordination Study (For Rushing Review))'

($baseName -replace '^.+#([^(]+).+$', '$1').TrimEnd()
```

The above yields
`26·0100-15.0·260100-015.00·-·Short·Circuit·&·Protective·Device·Coordination·Study`,
as expected.

In the context of your command:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\*Rushing*.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  ($_.BaseName -replace '^.+#([^(]+).+$', '$1').TrimEnd() + $_.Extension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are nice for this kind of string parsing.

Using your same logic of # at the start and (For Rushing Review) at the end, I set the new filename and extension as the two capture groups.

```
$Original = '210 8th Waverly Updated Submittal (#26 0100-15.0 260100-015.00 - Short Circuit & Proctective Device Coordination Study (For Rushing Review)).txt'
$Pattern = '^.+\(#(.+) \(For Rushing Review\).*(\..+)$'

$Original -Match $Pattern
$Matches[1]+$Matches[2]
```

[Regexr link for character-by-character breakdown](http://regexr.com/5fvv1)