# Script to remove PDF properties from JXML files

Tags: powershell, shell, automation

I have several Jasper reports with deprecated properties (`pdfFontName`, `pdfEncoding` and `isPdfEmbedded`) which cause the warning "PDF Font is deprecated and replaced by the Font Extension".

As there are many files to be corrected (maybe more than a thousand of them), I'm trying to come up with a script that automatically removes those properties and their values from the source code of the files (replaces the string in question with the empty string).

For example:

The following line of code of one of a file's source code:

```xml
<font fontName="Courier New" size="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="cour.ttf"/>
```

Would become:

```xml
<font fontName="Courier New" size="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" />
```

I already tried to ran this script on Windows Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "pathToFile" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.FullName).Replace('pdfFontName="\w+"','') | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

The property wasn't removed with this so I tried to replace the regular expression with the actual property value like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "pathToFile" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.FullName).Replace('pdfFontName="Helvetica"','') | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

It worked. For this reason, I think the problem has to do with the regular expression. I tried other regex but none of them worked. Can you help me correct this?

Comment: `.Replace` is not a regex operator, is for literal string replacement. you're looking for `-replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Santiago notes, **for [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based replacements, use the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator** rather than the `String` type's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method (the latter only performs *literal* replacements):

```
(Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace 'pdfFontName="\w+"', ''
```

Note:

- If the substitution operand is the empty string (`''`), it can be *omitted*.
- `-replace` - unlike `.Replace()` - is case-*insensitive* by default; use the `-creplace` variant for case-sensitivity.
- `-replace` builds on the (more powerful) [`[Regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace) .NET method; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335337/45375) for how they differ.

For guidance on **when to use `-replace` vs. `String.Replace()`**, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375).