# Remove Orphaned Carriage Returns from File

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have a daily process that downloads and parses pipe-delimited files into a database. Sometimes these files contain a single carriage return (no newline) at the end of one of the fields within a row, which breaks my process. My scheduler (not a windows scheduler, internal to our company) allows me to run batch or PowerShell processes on these files before loading them into the database, so I want to trim out any instance of orphaned carriage returns at the end of a field (\r|).

This PowerShell command works when run manually:

`` (Get-Content CarriageReturnTest.txt -Raw).Replace("`r|","|") | Set-Content CarriageReturnTest.txt -Force ``

However when I put this in the scheduler, I get an error that '","' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I realized the scheduler must be running a windows command of `PowerShell "{command}"` so the double quotes are making the command line think that I'm running several different commands. I tried replacing the double quotes in the PowerShell command with single quotes like so:

`` (Get-Content CarriageReturnTest.txt -Raw).Replace('`r|','|') | Set-Content CarriageReturnTest.txt -Force ``

This runs through the scheduler, but doesn't actually trim anything out of the file because PowerShell interprets the ` as an escape character when it's enclosed in single quotes.

I've tried escaping the double quotes with `` "", `", \", and ^" `` but nothing seems to work.

I realize there's some longer batch scripts I could write to handle this but ideally this would be a one liner to fit in the scheduler. I've also looked into saving the script as a ps1 file and running that with the file paths as arguments but I haven't gotten that to work either.

Comment: Use [`-replace` operator instead of the `.Replace` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10184156/3439404). Something like `-replace "\r\|",'|'`

Comment: @JosefZ This got me on the right path, thanks! It adds an extra \r\n to the end of my file for some reason but that doesn't really hurt anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off what @JosefZ said I tried this and it worked:

`(Get-Content CarriageReturnTest.txt -Raw) -replace('\r\|','|') | Set-Content CarriageReturnTest.txt -Force`

The `-replace` let me use regex in single quotes `'\r'` instead of `` "`r" ``in double, which kept me from escaping