# Replace a Multiline String using Regex in PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, multiline

I am trying to achieve this but it is working in Notepad++ but not in PowerShell+regex

File: 1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
```

PS:

```
(Get-Content E:\1.txt).replace("(?ms)1((?:.*\r?\n?)*)4", "success") | Set-Content E:\2.txt
```

I have tried with ?ms, ?s and ?m.

Any help?

Comment: `Get-Content E:\1.txt -Raw` and no need for any `m` or `s`

Comment: Still the same the content of the file is 1<newline>2<newline>3<newline>4<newline><newline>..

what i am trying to achieve is I know "1" and "4" with any text or line inbetween to be replaced with word success
(Get-Content E:\1.txt -raw).replace("1((?:.*\r?\n?)*)4", "success") | Set-Content E:\2.txt

Comment: Oh, you used `String.Replace`. Use `-replace`. Another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184156/whats-the-difference-between-replace-and-replace-in-powershell

Comment: <div class="he4h"><span tabindex=0 class=sectionTitle>sample</span><div class=he4h><span>Other</span>

My Objective is to remove from <div class="he4h"><span tabindex=0 class=sectionTitle>sample... till...</div>other
PS Script looks like this 
$start = '<div class="he4h"><span tabindex="0" class="sectionTitle">sample'
$end = '<div class="he4h"><span tabindex="0" class="sectionTitle">Other'
$regexpattern = '((?:.*\r?\n?)*)'
$searchString = $start+$regexpattern+$end
$a -replace '$searchString','mytext' | out-file "d:\a22.html"
this it just hangs.. Any idea on where i am getting it wrong

Comment: The regex to match from `1` to `4` is `(?s)1.*?4`