# Powershell - Replace multiple 5-digit substrings in a string

Tags: powershell, replace, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

We have customers that do not mention our INV-prefix when they pay invoices so I want to add it to our MT940-bank statement file.

> :20: :25:MHAZNL2AXXX/0376603160 :28C:102/ :60F:C220525EUR5000,
> :61:2204130413C336,52NMSCTOPF2500472627//GBBR001SCT TOPF2500472627
> :86:17136 17364 17382 032022102402 WONG TONG SARL 1 RUESOMETHINGPARIS
> SOGEFRPPXXX NOT PROVIDED
> :61:2204200420C406,02NMSCTOPF2500479378//GBCJ005SCT TOPF2500479378
> :86:17486 17586 17697 17813 0320221054201 WONG TONG SARL 1RUE
> SOMETHINGPARIS SOGEFRPPXXX  NOTPROVIDED

I need it to be

> :20:   :25:MHAZNL2AXXX/0376603160   :28C:102/   :60F:C220525EUR5000,
> :61:2204130413C336,52NMSCTOPF2500472627//GBBR001SCT TOPF2500472627
> :86:**INV**17136 **INV**17364 **INV**17382 032022102402 WONG TONG SARL 1
> RUESOMETHINGPARIS SOGEFRPPXXX NOT PROVIDED
> :61:2204200420C406,02NMSCTOPF2500479378//GBCJ005SCT TOPF2500479378
> :86:**INV**17486 **INV**17586 **INV**17697 **INV**17813 0320221054201 WONG TONG SARL
> 1RUE SOMETHINGPARIS SOGEFRPPXXX  NOTPROVIDED

I use a switch statement to match other lines as well that is why I use switch.

```
switch -Regex -File c:\Temp\WONG.ged  {
    ':86:.+WONG TONG.+'   { $_.replace('([1234567]\d{4}[ ])', "INV$1") }
    default               { $_ } # unrelated line, pass through
    }
```

This seems to [work](https://regex101.com/r/0eYJ8E/1) but the replace does not work (if I replace eg. WONG for TEST then it works fine).
I added 1234567 to prevent it from matching too much but it still matches too much.

Comment: `.replace( )` doesnt know what regex is, you probably wanted to use `-replace`

Comment: See [What's the difference between .replace and -replace in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10184156/3832970)

Comment: And you need `'INV$1'` or ``"INV`$1"``

Comment: But your regex is also off. There is no `WING SENG`, there is `WONG TONG`

Comment: I think you just need `(Get-Content $filepath) -replace '(\G(?!^)|^(?=:86:.+WONG TONG))(.*?)([1234567]\d{4}(?!\S))', '$1$2INV$3'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

- You need to use the `-replace` operator that supports regex replace operation, not the `String.Replace` method (see [What's the difference between .replace and -replace in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10184156/3832970))
- Your text does not contain `WING SENG`, so there is no match
- When you define a backreference, you need to use a literal `$`, so either use single quotes around the replacement, `'INV$1'`, or escape the backtick, `` "INV`$1" ``.

This will yield the expected result:

```
switch -Regex -File c:\Temp\WONG.ged {
 ':86:.+WONG TONG'   { $_ -replace '[1-7]\d{4} ', 'INV$&' }
 default             { $_ } # unrelated line, pass through
}
```

Note the pattern looks a bit different: `[1-7]` is shorter and leaner than a verbose `[1234567]` and there is no need to enclose the whole pattern with a capturing group, you can refer to the whole match with the `$&` backreference. Also, there is no need to add `.+` at the end of the regex.

There is an alternative solution:

```
(Get-Content $filepath) -replace '(\G(?!^)|^(?=:86:.+WONG TONG))(.*?)([1-7]\d{4}(?!\S))', '$1$2INV$3'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2A3Yt3/3). *Details*:

- `(\G(?!^)|^(?=:86:.+WONG TONG))` - Group 1: either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) a string (here, line) start position (`^`) that is immediately followed with `:86:`, any one or more chars other than line feed char, as many as possible, and then `WON TONG` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any zero or more chars other than line feed chars as few as possible
- `([1-7]\d{4}(?!\S))` - Group 3 (`$3`): a digit from `1` to `7` and then any four digits that are at the end of string or immediately followed with a whitespace.

`(Get-Content $filepath)` reads the file line by line, so any lines that are not matched will be output as is, unaffected.